# How to create abstraction in php?

Tags: php, oop

My purpose is to create two types graphics in php: pie, linear and represent data in each other.

Each graph should have own settings representation like: labels, texts.

In pie graph is required to display number of indicator as number or in percent.

I have begun with defenition of interface and abstract class:

```
interface IGraph {
  function percent();
  function percentGroup($type);
}

abstract class Graph implements IGraph {
  abstract function source();
  abstract function percent();
  abstract function percentGroup($type);
}

class GraphPie extends Graph {
  function source() {}
  function percent() {}
  function percentGroup($type) {}
}
```

I realized that should be a common abstract class `Graph` and custom classes as `GraphPie`, `GraphLinear`.

My problem is to create whole structure of classes for this task. For example, need I create another class as `GraphModelClass` where to write methods for retrieve data from db?

In other words I need to build functionality when I retrieve data by schema and can represent this in any graph.

I tried to adopt patterns in my case. I have reviewed patterns like: factory, facade, but it is not fit for me.

I follow this short [instruction](http://campus.murraystate.edu/academic/faculty/wlyle/430/rc008-designpatterns_online.pdf) about using patterns:

Comment: Will this be used for a commercial or non-commerical site?

Comment: It is for my own purposes, I am learn OOP

Comment: It often helps to create a first variant that does 100% of the work you think you need to deal with. Then take a slight break and review the work as a whole. Then decide how to implement it the second time and start writing from scratch. Then again to a break and then write the third implementation based on the experiences you got from the first two. Normally the third implementation has these questions answered for your case. Alternatively you can also - instead of writing your own code first, study two or three existing projects and read their source-code and documentation. Or just both.

Comment: Don't start with abstractions. Write concrete code first, then add abstractions if and when needed.

Comment: It is good recommendation, but I can not find examples the similar with my case to explore them. Only dry documentation that there are approaches to solve problems

Comment: So, I can to start write class that draws pie, but it will draw only concrete pie so it will be not reusable

Comment: @Karabah I agree with you. Abstractions are hard to master, you need to know from experience when to use which one. I've posted an answer for you that will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you only need an `interface` if your code is going to rely on different implementations of other code, that you or someone else wrote. You could use an `interface` if you're going to implement a single view for multiple data models. The view could then access the model which has its contract in the form of an interface.

But in your case you want to do it the other way around: to use a single model for the aggregated data with percentages and group names, with multiple views (line graph, pie chart) for the same kind of data.

You do not need to use object inheritance for that. Create a model to retrieve and store the data from the database. Then use that same model in each of your view classes that draw a line graph or a pie chart.

If your classes are named `GraphLine` and `GraphPie`, you could use single inheritance like this:

```
class GraphBase { /* generic draw functions, like labels */ }
class GraphLine extends GraphBase { /* Line graph specific drawing */ }
class GraphPie extends GraphBase { /* Pie chart specific drawing */ }
```

For the data, you could create a class `DataModel` like this

```
class DataModel {
  protected $iYear;
  public function setYear(int $iYear) : self {}
  public function getGraphData() : array { /* SQL SELECT .. GROUP BY .. */ }
}
```

And then in `GraphBase`:

```
class GraphBase {
  protected $oDataModel;
  public function setDataModel(DataModel $oDataModel) : self {
    $this->oDataModel = $oDataModel;
    return $this;
  }
  abstract function draw();  // GraphPie and GraphLine should implement this
}
```

Usage:

```
$Model = new DataModel;
$Model->setYear(2017);
$LineGraph = new GraphLine;
$LineGraph
  ->setDataModel($Model)
  ->draw();
```

Comment: So, where is class DataModel? May be to create `DataModel` and fill this object by data them put in concrete `GraphClass`? or retrive data directly in `GraphBase`?

Comment: Lets assume that we have method: `getData()` in `GraphBase` class. it is ok, but what if in the future I want to get data by condition like: `getData($where)`?

Comment: The condition would not change the output, it would still be group names with percentages. To add conditions you could add extra properties on the `DataModel` and make `getData()` use them. The views would not know the difference as the model is controlled outside of the view.

Comment: Do you mean create a new method in `DataModel` class?

Comment: So, I can add common methods in `GraphBase` as: `draw()`;

Comment: Yes you can implement common methods in `GraphBase` and specific ones in `GraphPie` and `GraphLine`

Answer (score 0):

As you're not going to be using it in a commercial context then you might want to consider using a ready-made library such as for example [JpGraph](https://jpgraph.net/)  **When using any 3rd party library, always check the licencing in case a paid for licence is required for commercial use of a library**

Comment: I try to learn myself to use OOP,  therefore I dont want to use ready solution